# Não consigo controlar o focus do formulário e a validação dos campos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou na seguinte situação, tenho três formularios, que são exibidos através do evento clique dos botões associados a eles, desabilito os botões e tento fazer a validação dos campos de cada formulário, antes de serem mostrados, tem uma imagem que desaparece quando clicado no botão, mas quando clico no botão de algum formulário, ela volta aparecer e habilita os botões novamente. Preciso manter o controle dos botões de envio de cada formulário e mostrar ambos mesmo quando entra na validação, porem, isso não ta acontecendo.

1) Formulario:

```
<div class="container-links">                                                                 
      <a class="btn btn-1" id="btn-reg1">Cliente 1</a> 
      <a class="btn btn-2" id="btn-reg2">Cliente 2</a>
      <a class="btn btn-3" id="btn-reg3">Cliente 3</a>                                                            
 </div> 
 <div class="imagem"><img src="images/pessoa.jpg"></div>
 <form id="pesquisadorForm" method="post">
     <div class="form-group                                               
       <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo"                    class="form-control">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     </div>                                                 

     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" class="form-control">                                                                                                                         
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" name="fone"  placeholder="Telefone" class="form-control">                                                                                                                         
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">                                                                                                                          
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="instituicao" placeholder="Institui&ccedil;&atilde;o" class="form-control">                                                                                                                         
    </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
    button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="btnPqdr" id="btnPqdr">Salvar Informa&ccedil;&otilde;es</button>                                                                            
 </div>                                                                                                                                                  
 </form>
```

2) Formulario

```
<form method="post" class="registration-form">
<div class="form-group">                                          
     <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo" class="form-control" >
</div>                                                            
<div class="form-group">                                        
  <input type="text" name="ocupacao" placeholder="Ocupa&ccedil;&atilde;o" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">                                        
 <input type="text" name="idade" placeholder="Idade" class="form-control">
</div>                              
<div class="form-group">                                        
  <input type="text" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">                                        
  <input type="text" name="uf" placeholder="UF" class="form-address form-control" id="form-address">
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Salvar Informa&ccedil;&otilde;es</button>                              
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Não sei se isto resolve o problema, mas observei que você usa elementos do formulário 1 e 2 com o mesmo 'name', os diferencie pois o DOM só irá fazer referencie ao primeiro que encontrar

Comment: Falha minha, não coloquei estes valores como estão aqui, por exemplo, no primeiro formulario, o input para o nome, tinha colocado no atributo name assim, "lbm-pesqd-nome", e para todo os restantes, segui definindo com esta idéia, só alterando o último nome, e assim defini para os outros dois formulários.